# What is the impact of system time zone of RHEL6 server in MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, timezone

We have a master server in EST time zone while slave is configured to follow  IST time zone but mysql on slave is configured with default_time_zone=EST5EDT just to make both DB instances follow same timezone , but If I execute

```
mysql > Select now();
```

on both servers I am getting same value , in contrast while I insert values in master instance using now()  it insert values in EST on master and in IST on slave which is causing data discrepancy in master and slave as far for data columns.
Below is the test I performed

```
 Master : (Having EST as system timezone)
 mysql> insert into test_timezone values (1,now());
  Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 mysql> insert into test_timezone values (2,now());
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 mysql> insert into test_timezone values (3,now());
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from test_timezone;
 +------+---------------------+
 | id   | date_tz             |
 +------+---------------------+
 |    1 | 2015-02-02 02:53:46 |
 |    2 | 2015-02-02 02:53:50 |
 |    3 | 2015-02-02 02:53:54 |
 +------+---------------------+

 Slave : (Having IST as system timezone but mysql default timezone is   EST5EDT)
 mysql> select * from test_timezone;
 +------+---------------------+
 | id   | date_tz             |
 +------+---------------------+
 |    1 | 2015-02-02 13:23:46 |
 |    2 | 2015-02-02 13:23:50 |
 |    3 | 2015-02-02 13:23:54 |
 +------+---------------------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So what needs to be done to get same time on master and slave while inserting/updating data ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is dependent on system time zone.

```
default-time-zone='TIMEZONE'
```

If this variable in not configured in my.cnf then MySQL will use system time zone to save and display data. If you want to have same time values in master and slave then ideal way is to configure

```
default-time-zone='TIMEZONE'
```

Above variable in master and slave this will have precedence over system time zone and you will have same time values in master and slaves.

If you don't find your required time zone in MySQL, please follow below link to populate time zones in MySQL database

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html